# HDinsight Store Pig Result

Tags: c#, .net, azure, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I want to submit a pig job with the .NET SDK to HDInsight (but it also happens when I submit it with PowerShell, tested that already).  Using following Statement:

```
 string queryString = "REGISTER wasb:///PigTestFolder/myudfs.jar;" +
                                 " A = LOAD 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/wordlist.txt' USING PigStorage()AS Line:chararray;" +
                                 " B =ORDER A BY Line asc;" +
                                 " D= Limit B 20;" +
                                 " Dump D;" +
                                 " STORE D INTO 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/results/' USING PigStorage ('\t');";
```

When I remove the STORE command everything works perfectly fine. But Storing the result to the BLOB is a pain in the arse. It say in the error log: "AS was unexpected at this time". But if I remove the schema and define the column with $0 it says: B was unexpected at this time.

The following Code prints out: Dump unexpected at this time.

```
string queryString = " A = LOAD 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/wordlist.txt' USING PigStorage();" +
                                 " Dump A;" +
                                 " STORE A INTO 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/results/' USING PigStorage ('\t');";
```

I tested the code with the Hortonworks Sandbox and it works. No problem. Another mystery is, when using only the following two lines of PigLatin code it works as well:

```
string queryString = " A = LOAD 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/wordlist.txt' USING PigStorage();" +

"STORE D INTO 'wasb:///PigTestFolder/results/' USING PigStorage ('\t');";
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is working now. Maybe Microsoft fixed that bug as I did not change anything about the query.